# Adding TextField without customizations keeps adding styles in head

Tags: material-ui

I'm new to MUI and wondering if I'm doing something wrong.
I noticed I had a page that lagged when using tabs. Doing some perf mon, I saw that most of the time was spent on style processing. Then did a document.querySelectorAll('head > style').length and saw I had over 664 entries.

So I built a simple test page:

```
import React from 'react'
import { TextField } from '@mui/material'

export default function TestPage(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextField name="test" />
      <TextField name="test" />
      <TextField name="test" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The first TextField adds 39 styles tags, and each subsequent TextField add 2 style tags, even if they all share the same properties.

Is there a way to tell MUI to reuse the same style when given the same properties ?

Here are my package versions:

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
 "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
 "@mui/system": "^5.8.6",
 "@mui/material": "^5.5.3",
 "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.8.0",
 "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-alpha.6"
```

Comment: What is the `sx` value that you are passing in `sx={sx}`? Your "simple test page" code doesn't define that.

Comment: Oh you're right sorry about that. I tried to define an empty object in the global scope and pass it to the prop to make sure they would have the same reference, but it yielded the same result.